# The Caret Sign ^ is not recognized in tesseract python

Tags: python-3.x, tesseract

I am working on a project in python. But I am stuck in a problem, my `tesseract` is not recognizing **^** sign.

.[image: Sample]

By doing ..

`pytesseract.image_to_string('sample.png')`

The result what i am getting is...

```
Find the remainder when -4x4 -
17x%3 + 15x42 + 12x +19 is divided
by -4x43 - 17x*2 + 7x + 14?
```

It misinterprets ^ with % , * , 4  etc....
How should i correct it?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to train Tesseract to add that character.

[Fine Tuning for ± a few characters](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract-4.00#fine-tuning-for--a-few-characters)

Answer (score 0):

use this tessdata >> [tessdata](https://github.com/abneetOSS/caret-trained)

It is trained with caret symbol (^) combined with tessdata_best eng.traineddata
you just create backup of /usr/share/tesseract/4/tessdata
and paste the downloaded tessdata folder to /usr/share/tesseract/4/tessdata
or your defined tessdata directory.